# React native - You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate

Tags: react-native, certificate, google-play-console, signing

I have uploaded an Expo project few months ago, I'm not sure I signed the app but running `expo fetch:android:keystore` gives me the following info:

> Keystore password
>
> Key alias
>
> Key password

I started a new project using React Native CLI so I generated a new keystore file using the data above, but Google Play shows me that error message after I tried to upload the release APK

```
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
```

What am I doing wrong? to be honest I'm not familiar with app signing on Google Play.
How can I upload a new APK from a new RN CLI project without changing the package name and deploying a new app? I don't wanna lose my current clients.

Answer (score 1):

So to anyone who will ever encounter this problem, what I did was copy the file `app_name.jks` from the expo project folder to `android/app` (RN CLI) and executed the command `expo fetch:android:keystore` (Expo project) to get the Keystore, Alias and Password of the Expo project.

Then changed the `android/app/build.gradle` (RN CLI)

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('app_name.jks')
        storePassword System.console().readLine("\nKeystore password: ")
        keyAlias 'here is the alias from the command above`'
        keyPassword System.console().readLine("\nKey password: ")
    }
}
```

Then executed the build command `./gradlew assembleRelease --no-daemon`, console log will ask for the password and the keystore password (from the expo command above) and that's it!

I was able to upload to Google Play using the same upload fingerprints

Comment: Thanks, i got the same problem from merging PR for RN update, and the default files overwrites this part, this answer helped me alot